# I have a patch for my laptop that needs to be added but I have no idea how to apply it

Tags: kernel, hp, bios, dv6

This is a link to the bug and people say it has been patched but I don't know how to apply the patch. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/529477  The bug is on the HP Dv6 pavilion laptops and it says the BIOS needs to be updated before suspend mode will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your bug but a bios update isn't that hard (a bit risky if done incorrectly but quite easy).

first make sure your battery is FULLY charged(!!!!!!!!).

secondly download the bios update from HP and burn is to a dvd (or if supported to a usb).

boot from the dvd (or usb) and install the bios update.

Some bios updates from hp can be (and in some rare cases HAVE TO BE) installed from windows. I would recommend installing it by booting from the dvd (or usb) but in some cases it is easier to winflash it. The choice is up to you.

here's HP's manual for updating your bios: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&docname=c00042629